# Cannot change logging settings per-user in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-13

I have a special database role that only handles passwords, and I want to exclude it from database logs, but include logs from all other users.

In my *postgresql.conf* file I have these custom settings:

```
log_destination = 'stderr,csvlog'
logging_collector = on
log_min_duration_statement = 6000
log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] %q%u@%d '
log_lock_waits = on
log_statement = 'all'           # none, ddl, mod, all
log_timezone = 'Asia/Jerusalem'
```

... and in my CREATE USER sql, I have these settings:

```sql
CREATE ROLE special_user WITH
  LOGIN
  SUPERUSER
  INHERIT
  NOCREATEDB
  NOCREATEROLE
  NOREPLICATION
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

ALTER ROLE special_user SET log_min_duration_statement TO '-1';
ALTER ROLE special_user SET log_statement TO 'none';
```

...and yet, the queries from this special user still appear in the logs.
I'm using PostgreSQL 13.10.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That should work fine, but only in sessions that connected *after* you ran `ALTER ROLE`.

Comment: This should work to countermand log_statement and log_min_duration_statement if you logged in with the special user, but there may be other ways for things to show in the logs.  And if you became the special user via `SET ROLE`, it won't work for that.  Also, there is no reliable way to render the logs innocuous enough that you can blindly share them with untrusted users.